# Cross Domain Windows Authentication "Allowed to Authenticate" not working

Tags: windows, active-directory, authentication, cross-reference, iis-8

We have couple of websites which is working on different servers and all are internally connected with the LAN. All websites are using windows authentication.

Now I would like to use Single Sign ON for the same. We will create a primary website with windows authentication and all other websites will have hyper link at primary page. If user is authenticated with primary one then he must be able to access other application as well. Currently when user click on other website, he is getting Credentials prompt again. We want to suppress this login prompt.

All websites which are connected have same user credentials and same Active directory group. But still it prompting.

From the Google results I found this update

"AD Users and Computers --> enable Advanced Features --> Select the Computer Object --> Properties --> Security --> Add the Group which want to allow access to the computer (in this case, DomainA\Domain users) and allow "Allowed to Authenticate"."

But still not working.

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Laxmi Lal Menaria

Comment: Windows authentication for a website is typically handled by the browser. You simply need to make sure the appropriate settings are applied to each browser so that they will pass the user credential. This typically involves putting each domain in to the trusted / local intranet site list or adding it to other necessary settings in other browsers. https://ping.force.com/Support/%20PingFederate/Integrations/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM

Comment: Please clarify if the users/computers and website servers are all part of the same active directory domain?

Comment: yes, all users and websites servers in same ADS.

Answer (score -1):

if all the servers are windows server and you have AD domain...enable kerberos delegation on the other servers.....goto AD users and computers....under computers.....look for all server one by one------right click---properties....goto delegation tab and enable kerberos deleation